# How to addEventListener in React if element came from Markdown (i dont even have it im my files)?

Tags: reactjs, addeventlistener

I have markdown comments whene users can add their own layout (`ul, li, b, img, a`, etc)

And i want to addEventListener to ALL images which were added by users.

[Example with image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcikf.png)

Here you can see - User add completely new image from Web and i want to add an EventListener to this image.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: So, it's impossible to do with React?

Comment: You can add that from React (inside a `useEffect`). Some libraries also provide you with a `useMutationObserver` hook.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community I didn't get it. 
Almost all my questions require some changes. 

And when I read them I can't even realize what might not be clear??

1) I've  told my situation
2) Show screenshot
3) Ask what I want to do with this info. 

Specific problem - How to addEventListener in React for element which wasn't in my project?

What else do I need to tell or show????